# /EFS partition won't mount in Samsung I9300 International SIII

Tags: android

I tried flashing a rom on the device with a lower version of TeamWin Recovery than it was advised in the rom post on XDA.
as a result the data partition wouldn't mount which was solved later by flashing a stock rom with Odin and Factory resetting the device.

during the time i was trying to solve the /Data not mounting, I tried something that I later found out was for a different problem...
these are the commands that I used: [Link](http://zidroid.com/how-to-fix-failed-to-mount-efs-for-galaxy-s3-gt-i9300/)

```
adb shell
mke2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
mount -w -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
reboot
```

After that the /EFS Partition doesn't mount and as a result I have no cellular reception.

Please tell me what I have done wrong and why /EFS doesn't mount.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had formatted the /EFS entirely...
gave it to a service center and they repaired it..